# Why am I getting a "BackgroundTask" error in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode11

Xcode V11.2.1 running iOS 13.2 simulator.

I've tested multiple sample apps and getting the same error whenever I switch the app using the simulator home button or swipe up.

The error I am getting in Xcode is: "Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 2 (0x2)  [[[or identifier ` (0x1)]]], or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @DIV I was a newbie too not too long ago. Unfortunately I don't have an answer to give, but I may help you with the question itself.
Try to make it short I mean way short :D, and add code blocks for the lines of code you have instead of plain text. work on your title more to make catchy to those who are familiar with the topic.
I think this article will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Wissa...  BTW... I solved my initial issue and the BackgroundTask error is not preventing my code from running.  The Background Task error appears to be independent of code so I re-posted with your suggestion.